# Running Python3 program using tkinter in the console (command line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My Python3 program contains *Tkinter*. It runs properly in *Idle3* and it runs properly in the *LXTerminal*.

It will not run in the console. In the console (command-line) I get the following error message:

```
File "/usr/lib/Python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.PY",line 1712,
  in_init_self.tk=tkinter.create(screenName,baseName,className,interactive,wantobjects,useTk,sync,use)_tkinter.TCLError:
  no display name and no $DISPLAY envronment variable.
```

I am using the latest NOOBS installation for *Raspbian*.

This is the code I am running -

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=300, height=200)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because the terminal you're trying to run your program in does not have access to an X instance, whereas it tries to access it.

I'm not sure and can't tell whether this is because TkInter assumes it needs X on import or because your code is explicitly creating a graphical object whereas you're running it in the consel.